# inserting duplicate record LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have tried to insert using the below LINQ queries. Somehow I am getting a duplicate record for the **id**.  Can some one help me with details?

```
try {
 OLA_ASSESSMENT_DTL OAD = db.OLA_ASSESSMENT_DTL.SingleOrDefault(
  ev => ev.OAD_RIV_ID == id);

 transaction = "Modify"; // resetting the value of the variable
 if (OAD == null) {
  transaction = "Add";
  OAD = new OLA_ASSESSMENT_DTL();
 }
 OAD.OAD_PER_RELAIONSHIP = relationshipfocus.relationshipfocus;
 OAD.OAD_PER_RELAIONSHIP_COMMENT = CRecHelper.CheckIsNullString(relationshipfocus.strrelationshipfocus).ToString();
 OAD.OAD_RIV_ID = id;     
 OAD.OAD_MODIFIED_DATE = DateTime.Now;
 if (transaction == "Add") {
  db.OLA_ASSESSMENT_DTL.Add(OAD);
 }
 db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Whether it's a new object or not, you always assign the id: `OAD.OAD_RIV_ID = id;`. How do you expect **not** to get a duplicate?

Comment: Are you inserting new record or trying to update the existing record by Id?

Comment: @NaveenKN K N - I am trying to update the existing record by ID if there is  a record present for the ID. at the same time inserting into the same table with that ID if there is no record

Comment: There is no LinQ here except for the single call to `SingleOrDefault`. Did you maybe mean [tag:Linq-to-Entities] or [tag:entity-framework]?

Answer (score 0):

At first, you correctly detect duplicate record (though you probably should use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `SingleOrDefault`, but that's a detail):

```
OLA_ASSESSMENT_DTL OAD = db.OLA_ASSESSMENT_DTL.SingleOrDefault(
       ev => ev.OAD_RIV_ID == id);

transaction = "Modify"; // resetting the value of the variable
if (OAD == null)
{
    transaction = "Add";
    OAD = new OLA_ASSESSMENT_DTL();
}
```

But later, you casually assign the id to the object, even when you know it is a duplicate:

```
OAD.OAD_RIV_ID = id;
```

First, remove that line because it's useless:

- if the record already exists, then you're just overwriting the id with its current value
- if the record is duplicate, then you're setting the duplicated id on the new record

Instead, set a unique id when you know the record is duplicate, following whichever strategy you've defined for your table:

```
OLA_ASSESSMENT_DTL OAD = db.OLA_ASSESSMENT_DTL.SingleOrDefault(
       ev => ev.OAD_RIV_ID == id);

transaction = "Modify"; // resetting the value of the variable
if (OAD == null)
{
    transaction = "Add";
    OAD = new OLA_ASSESSMENT_DTL();
    // TODO: Assign a unique id, or let the database assign one if the column is auto-increment
}
```

Comment: I missed to create a unique constraint for the column OAD_RIV_ID. But I have some other columns in this table for running number. Now, Why I am getting the duplicate record while use the **Id** value. I suspect that tow requests has been send immediately (doubleclick) before I reach the db.SaveChanges();for the first time second request is getting updated as transaction=Add. Will there be any possibility for this

Comment: I missed to create a unique constraint for the column OAD_RIV_ID. But I have some other columns in this table for running number. Now, Why I am getting the duplicate record while use the Id value. I suspect that tow requests has been send immediately (doubleclick) before I reach the db.SaveChanges();for the first time second request is getting updated as transaction=Add. Will there be any possibility for this